# Running migrations post_restart vs. pre_restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Can someone explain what is the difference between running a rails migration post_restart vs pre_restart? What restart is it referring to? I'm working with the [handcuffs](https://github.com/procore/handcuffs) gem but not really sure what it does. An example of when to use either phase would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

These phases just are example, you can define whatever phase you want, example: `beta`, `production`.

I think the idea is when you defined phase for migrations, you can run migrations of a specify phase instead of running all migrations.

So, If you run `rake db:migrate`, it will run all pending migrations, but if you run:

```
rake 'handcuffs:migrate[beta]'
```

it will run only pending migrations of beta phase.